# Wordpress menu add class in a tag

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to create simple bootstrap navigation for my theme, Here I have html code like that

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">ABOUT US</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

For desire output I have written

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container'=> false, 'menu_class'=> 'navbar-nav mx-auto' ) ); ?>
```

I got the result like

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a  href="#">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a  href="#">ABOUT US</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a  href="#">CONTACT</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

How can I add `class = "nav-link"` in `a` tag ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy by [nav_menu_link_attributes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_link_attributes/)

```
function menu_anchors( $atts ) {
    $atts['class'] = 'nav-link';

    return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'menu_anchors' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please put below function in your function file and change with your menu location:

```
function add_specific_menu_location_atts( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    // check if the item is in the primary menu
    if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' ) {
      // add the desired attributes:
      $atts['class'] = 'nav-link';
    }
    return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_specific_menu_location_atts', 10, 3 );
```